# Capistrano `bundler failed to load command: cap`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, rbenv

I am working on a Rails 3.2 app and it is uses Capistrano 2.15.5 for deploying to production.

When I run `bundle exec cap deploy` I get `bundler: failed to load command: cap (/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/bin/cap)`

`which cap` returns `/.rbenv/shims/cap`

I think I need to change the path to hit `/.rbenv/shims/cap`, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

deploy.rb

```
    require 'bundler/capistrano'
    require 'capistrano/deploy_lock'



    set :application, "website"

    set :repository, "git@github.com:my_company/website.git"
    set :branch,     "master"
    set :scm,        "git"
    set :user,       "root"

    set :deploy_to,    "/home/rails/#{application}"
    set :deploy_via,   "remote_cache"
    set :copy_exclude, ".git/*"
    set :use_sudo,      false
    set :keep_releases, 3
```

Capfile

```
# capistrano default tasks
load 'deploy'

# Rails' asset pipeline cap tasks
load 'deploy/assets'

# Vendored gem and plugin cap tasks
Dir['vendor/gems/*/recipes/*.rb','vendor/plugins/*/recipes/*.rb'].each { |plugin| load(plugin) }

# Cap tasks defined in project's deploy.rb file
load 'config/deploy'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We hit this issue because we weren't using password-less (i.e. key) deploys. According to the [README](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/README.md#key-based-ssh) :

> Capistrano depends on connecting to your server(s) with SSH using key-based (i.e. password-less) authentication".

We were using an old version of Capistrano (2.15.5) and password based deploys were working. The breaking change was upgrading the `net-ssh` gem from 2.7.0 to 4.2.0.

I think your options are to specify an old version of the `net-ssh` gem:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'net-ssh', '2.7.0'
```

Or to set up key-based SSH to your servers. This is what we did & would recommend as it allows you to move forwards.